# Referencing a Cell .send Syntax Error // Web Scraping

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

Background/objective: Web Scrape: Problem with the Syntax using the .send

I am attempting to send the last name and first name from a list of names in two columns of cells, I am coming across Syntax Errors as it does not recognize the cell and assumes the range is the "name"

code:
The syntax error begins on the "last" and "first" line under the .send, as I am attempting to send a cell value rather than type in the name. What is the correct formatting when referencing a range of cells?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim sContent As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim aHeader() As String
    Dim aRows() As String

    ' Retrieve HTML content via XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "http://npinumberlookup.org/getResults.php", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send _
            "last=Range(G:1)" & _
            "&first=Range(F:1)" & _
            "&pracstate=TX" & _
            "&npi=" & _
            "&submit=Search"
```

Comment: Range("F1:G1")?  Or Range("F1") etc....  .Value or .Text properties of said ranges.

Comment: I was testing with just one cell f1 since I am still learning how to loop for the following names.

Comment: Normally last would =smith and first =john but I am trying to reference from existing cells.

Comment: "last = " & Range("G1") .Text ? I am unsure how you expect this to compile and am unable to test myself. The correct syntax for a single cell range would be Range("G1") and you can access its properties such as .Value and .Text . You should also fully qualify the range with the worksheet name and workbook (these can be via variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to reference the value of a Range, is exactly as @Qharr said before.  I tried doing:

```
' Retrieve HTML content via XHR
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", "http://npinumberlookup.org/getResults.php", False
    .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send _
        "last=" & Range("G1").Value & _
        "&first=" & Range("F1").Value & _
        "&pracstate=TX" & _
        "&npi=" & _
        "&submit=Search"
End With
```

And it worked. No errors when running the code.